# Book about a girl with a birthmark shaped like a wheel who runs away from home

Tags: story-identification, novel, fairy-tales

I read this really good book recently, but can't seem to remember the name. It's about this girl who has a birth mark of a spinning wheel. She decides to run away from her home, for reasons explained in the book. When she runs away she meets a series of odd people. Soon she learns that everyone in that town also has a weird birthmark. Each birthmark has to do with a specific fairy tale. The main character soon learns age is destined to fall into a 100 year sleep, like Sleeping Beauty.

Comment: Welcome to SFF:SE. I recommend taking the [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour)  to get yourself up to speed on how we do things here. Also, do you mean "The main character soon learns *she* is destined to fall into a 100 year sleep"?

Answer (score 4):

*[Kill Me Softly](https://muse.jhu.edu/article/474130/summary)* by Sarah Cross, first book of the *Beau Rivage* series, which seems to consist of two books and some short stories. Found by searching for `book birthmark "spinning wheel"` (bolding mine):

[image: Kill Me Softly - book cover]

> At fifteen, Mirabelle commits her first act of rebellion by running away to Beau Rivage, the hometown of her late parents and a place expressly forbidden by her strict, overprotective godmothers. Among the fairy-tale themed casinos and skeevy hotels, Mira meets a host of teens with strange characteristics (a girl whose mouth [End Page 450] " drips jewels, a boy who can seemingly enchant animals), **each bearing a birthmark** that curses them to fulfill **a role in a particular fairy tale**; Mira shares a similar mark, in the **vague shape of a spinning wheel**. Before she can play out her fate as Sleeping Beauty, however, she falls in love with Felix, a boy marked as a villain whose role would inevitably cost Mira her life, unless she can change both their destinies....

Comment: @Kenna-D: If this is the answer, don't forget to accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.